# how to set username password for hbmqtt in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mqtt, messagebroker

I know how to connect to broker by hbmqtt in script bash:

```
 hbmqtt_sub --url mqtt://guest:guest@localhost:15672 -t a/b
```

but in my code where i use hbmqtt library how can I set username and password

```
async def test_sub():
    client = MQTTClient()
    await client.connect(' mqtt://guest:guest@localhost:15672')
    await client.subscribe([
        ('a/b', QOS_1),
    ])
```

this code doesnt work!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: it needs username and password in proper way, i use rabbitmq broker

Comment: are you try this? client.username_pw_set(username="name",password="pwd")

Comment: Maybe you mix up with port number? `5672` is default rabbitmq port. Also I see a extra whitespace in connection string at the start.

Comment: @СергейКрылов Does hbmqtt client have this attribute?

Comment: @Eugenij no it works in my browser on this port

Comment: @amirhossein Yes, you are right. Rabbitmq uses port `15672` for web UI and port `5672` for connection. Plz try `5672` in connection string

Comment: @Eugenij it gives me this error: hbmqtt.errors.HBMQTTException: Invalid fixed packet type 4 for ConnackPacket init

Comment: The error implies that the that RabitMQ is listening on that port is not MQTT as it is sending a response the client doesn't understand.

Comment: @hardillb so how should I config it, should I make config file?

Comment: No idea, I don't use rabbitMQ. Do as I asked on your other question and include the details of how you have configured rabbitMQ so somebody that does can tell if it's correct